# how to apply DIAL 2.0 smooth pairing?

Tags: cobalt

we checkout Cobalt 10.49488 and modify some codes that pass URL to cobalt.
we check RC_9 release note, it should apply DIAL 2.0 smooth pairing.

so we can deliver "https://www.youtube.com/tv?wired=1&pairingCode=9613cf31-19c5-4045-8d41-0b4d18ad2330&theme=cl&additionalDataUrl=http://localhost:55868/dialData?app=YouTube" to cobalt "BrowserModule::Navigate()" for smooth pairing.
then Youtbe(cobalt) will pair with my smartphone, smartphone seem it work properly also.
after we check the dial flow, we found we did not receive "/dialData" and "screenId".

could you help us check our implemention about dial smooth pairing?
or an exmaple?

Comment: It looks like this may be YouTube not serving up the CSP permission to contact http://localhost. I think this is likely to be a bug, if you want to file it on our public tracker.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Cobalt RC_9 or Cobalt 10, DIAL Smooth Pairing relies on some additional server side configuration, and those changes were pushed ~ May 8, 2017.

Smooth Pairing should work now using RC_9 or Cobalt 10.

Comment: What's the difference with RC_9 and cobalt master branch? It seemed the changes on RC_9 and cobalt master branch are not the same, are all the changes on RC_9 branch  included in the cobalt master branch?

Comment: Cobalt 9 is the release that targets YouTube 2017 technical requirements specification.

Master branch is where all the development happens.  I think the idea is that every branch is cut from master, and stabilized for use in production platforms.  If you have futher questions, please create a new stack overflow question, as this is not related to the original question.